# NameNotFoundException while deploying using jython

Tags: jms, jndi, jython, websphere-8, ibm-was

I am deploying EAR file through jython script on IBM WAS but at the time of deploying I am getting error and application not coming up.

ERROR CODE:

```
     J2CA0052E: The lookup of the Activation Specification with JNDI Name jms/SampleQueueListener failed due to the following exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: cell01/nodes/dmgr11/servers/dmgr, name: jms/SampleQueueListener: First component in name jms/SampleQueueListener not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
```

The `jms/SampleQueueListener` is already there.  I am using WAS 8.5.5.8 and deploying application through Jython script on Linux OS and I am also using node agent and dmgr.

**python Script to deploy app:**

```
def installapps():
try:
    print "********************************************************"
    print "Installing  Application in IBM WAS"
    print "********************************************************"
    print "\n Installing ear file -- %s " % eFile 
    AdminApp.install(eFile,["-usedefaultbindings", "-BindJndiForEJBMessageBinding",[["samplesystemservice.jar", "ServiceActivator", "sampleservices.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml", "SampleQueueListener", "jms/SampleQueueListener", "jms/SampleJMSQueue"], ["sampleystemservices.jar", "BootstrapMessageBean", "samplesystemservices.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml", "SampleTopicListener", "jms/SampleTopicListener", "jms/SampleJMSTopic"]]])
AdminConfig.save()
print "***************hello22***********"
AdminApp.install(wFile, ["-appname", wName, "-contextroot", ctxroot])
print "***************hello33**********"
    AdminConfig.save()
    print "Completed installing applications.\n"
    print "Saving configuration. This may take time, please wait...."
    print "********************************************************\n"
    print "********************************************************"
    print "Completed the installation of  Application in IBM WAS"
    print "********************************************************"
except:
    AdminControl.stopServer("server1", node)
print "Unable to install  Application"
print "********************************************************"
sys.exit(0)
try:
    print "********************************************************"
    print "Stop the WAS for post configuration of  Application"
    AdminControl.stopServer("server1", node)    
except:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fix your script. Currently you are deploying your app to `dmgr` server, see the context:

`Context: cell01/nodes/dmgr11/servers/dmgr, name: jms/SampleQueueListener`

The dmgr server is only for management, not for deploying your own apps and resources. You need to provide nodeName and serverName or clusterName, if you are deploying to the ND environment. Usually the server for apps is called `server1`. If you dont have any server you may need to create it.

I'd suggest using web admin console first, until you have better knowledge about your topology and management.

**UPDATE**

You need to map modules to the correct servers, see `MapModulesToServers` option, like this:

```
AdminApp.install('DefaultApplication.ear', ['-appname', 'TEST', '-MapModulesToServers', [['.*', 
 '.*', 'WebSphere:cell=myCell,node=myNode,server=myServer']]])
```

Or you can use provided scripts from library, which may be easier and more convenient:

```
AdminApplication.installAppWithNodeAndServerOptions(appName, earFile,
 nodeName, serverName)
```

See also:

- [Application installation and uninstallation scripts](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_7libapp.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-18-4-3&lang=en)
- [Options for the AdminApp object install](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html?lang=en)
- [Commands for the AdminApp](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_adminapp.html?lang=en)

Comment: Hi gas, I am using scope node name Do i need to provide server name as well.

Comment: Resources can be installed on node, but apps only on servers/clusters. Your app somehow got installed on `dmgr`, which is incorrect. You have to install it on other server. You can define resources on Node that this server belongs to.

Comment: Hi Gas, I have added jython script which in am using to deploy app on server. Could you please let me know where i am doing wrong.